# How to make line-through wider/bigger than text/element using CSS

Tags: html, css, line-through

Can you please let me know how I can force CSS to make the `line-through` property wider than element `width`?

For Example

```
<h3 style="text-decoration:line-through">50</h3>
```

and result looks like [image] now how I can make the line wider than element to be more obvious?

Like [image]

Comment: The width of the strike is the width of the text (not the width of the element, which equals the available total width for a block element like `h3`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` which is a cheesy way to go for

```
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KstMt/)

---

Or you can do is, use `:before` and `:after` pseudo with `content` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KstMt/1/)

```
div {
    text-decoration:line-through;
}

div:before,
div:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
```

**Note**: Using a *general selector* here, consider using `class` or an `id` to target the element specifically, also, if your text is between other text, consider wrapping that in a span and than use `:before` and `:after` over `span`.

---

Briefing an answer here with solution that uses CSS Positioning techniques, using which you can also control the thickness of the strike through..

Here, am positioning the child element `absolute` to the parent element. So make sure you declare `position: relative;` on parent. Rest, `:after` pseudo handles the rest and also be sure that you use `content: "";`, though it's blank, it's mandatory.

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/KstMt/2/) *(Using CSS Positioning)*

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    left: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
padding: N px;
line-height: N px;
```

`&nbsp;` in html
Nested Div's `<div><div></div></div>`