# Make a strikethrough line go more down

Tags: html, css

How can I make a strikethrough line go more down for example

```
<p style="text-decoration: line-through;">HELLO</p>
```

*[**View my fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XRAeM/show/)* for images because I need 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503364/can-i-change-the-vertical-position-of-a-strike-through-on-a-website

Comment: @megawac It doesn't have the answer that I need

Comment: @mplungjan I did search but here is the search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Make+a+strikethrough+line+go+more+down

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strike-through+position

Comment: I just answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495082/how-to-make-css-strike-through-wider-than-element/21495115#21495115), use CSS positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is only one line, this will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/delvarworld/KmE4q/

html:

```
<stricken>HELLO</stricken>
```

sass:

```
stricken {
    position:relative;

    &:after {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:32px;
        height:4px;
        background:#000;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

If your text is multiple lines, you would need to wrap each line in a `<striken>` tag, and not rely on browser word wrapping.

Comment: I'm using css not sass

Comment: Then stop using css and start using sass

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with the strikethrough. 
one of my project I have same requirement, I have done it with some css trick but this is not good practice.

**html**

```
<div>HELLO<hr/></div>
```

**css**

```
div{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
hr{
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;
    left:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/qtFnf/)**

Comment: But what if I make the font-size bigger

Comment: make the hr line top position 58%, it will work fine in all font size.

Answer (score 0):

text-decoration:line-through;  doesnt support the positioning of line. So, we cant do any change in that, it deppends on font as well. Possibly as a solution what we can do is to replace line with border and position it according to your needs

```
.center:after {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
position: absolute;
content: "";
right: 0;
top:65%;
left: 0;
}

Refer this:-
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFPxL/